# Long version of function in JS

Tags: javascript

```
field.on('change', ({error}) => {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
    }
});
```

I don't have much experience in JS and I wonder how the "long" version of this JS part looks (with the classic function keyword).

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can throw it in [babeljs.io repl](https://babeljs.io/repl#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=GYSwpgNgJgdA9gOwBQHIDGALAhgg5mFAGgAIkBvMAJ0rkoF8BKYgXgD5iyAoYn4kYUlRqUmXXuOJpEAZzgQwMCHFxIhtGAFsw06VnwMA3N151OjA0A&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=true&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Ces2016%2Ces2017%2Clatest%2Creact%2Cstage-0%2Cstage-1%2Cstage-2%2Cstage-3%2Ces2015-loose&prettier=false&targets=&version=6.26.0&envVersion=). If you do so, you will get:

```
'use strict';

field.on('change', function (_ref) {
    var error = _ref.error;

    if (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
    }
});
```

BabelJS is a so called transpiler, that can convert back new or proposed javascript features to the old syntax.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this:

```
field.on('change', function ({error}) {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
    }
});
```

Comment: The curly braces confused me, what do they mean?

Comment: That's a thing called destructuring. See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment. In short: the function receives an object with `error` property, so that we don't have to do this: `function (obj)  { const error = obj.error; if (error) ... }`

Answer (score 0):

Arrow function will be replaced by normal function.

```
field.on('change', function(error) {
if (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
}
});
```